# Is it possible to access local variables with ByteBuddy's Advice?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, byte-buddy

When intercepting a method's implementation with an `@Advice`, is it possible to access local variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not and this is partly by design. A method's implementation is supposed to be a private detail whereas advice adds code after and before an invocation where the method's signature is part of its API.

At some point, Byte Buddy might offer a possibility to replace certain field and method accesses but in a way that you do not rely on an implementation.

In order to mingle with the explicit byte code, Byte Buddy offers `AsmVisitorWrapper` to use the ASM API directly which is better suited for byte code-level manipulation than Byte Buddy's high-level API.